# Indexing through a list using for and while loops Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

For a list index in python, I understand that the index starts at 0. For example in my list of list that I have created:

```
lst = [['Youngstown', ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436]], ['Yankton', ['SD', 4288, 9739, 12011, [966]]], ['Yakima', ['WA', 4660, 12051, 49826, [1513, 2410]]]...]

lst[2]: ['Yakima', ['WA', 4660, 12051, 49826, [1513, 2410]]] #would be index 2
```

And the following would be the used if I was trying to find [1513, 2410]:

```
lst[2][1][4]: [1513, 2410]
```

So I was trying to compare a number to all the numbers in the following index range: lst[i][1][4] where i = 0

So I thought I could use a while loop to do this but it keeps saying it is out of range.

```
a = 0
l = []
while(a < len(lst)):
    i = 0
    for j in range(len(lst[i][1][4])):
        if 1000 < j:
            l.append(lst[a])
        i += 1
    a += 1
```

Here is the error I receive:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#38>", line 3, in 
for j in range(len(lst[i][1][4])):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Look at the very first item in `lst`. What does the index `lst[0][1][4]` give you?

Comment: Also, remember that you can iterate over lists directly. Using `while a < len(lst):` or `for j in range(len(lst)):` are both anti-patterns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to access the N'th item mean that my list has less than N items?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1098643/90527)

Answer (score 0):

The first time through the `while` loop, `i` is 0, so you're trying to access `lst[0][1][4]`.

`lst[0][1]` is `['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436]`.  It has 4 elements, so index `[4]` (the fifth element) is out of range.